# Can't update the Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: android-studio

I am running Android Studio 3.4.1 and I'm trying to build a [bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle).

```
Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build Bundle(s)
```

And here is what I see:

[image]

When I click `Update`, the dialog dismisses and absolutely nothing happens. I have tried several times.

I also have this:

[image]

I am very new to Android Studio, but my simple app is complete and ready to deploy to the Google Play Store. Is there some alternate way to build a bundle? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** make sure in your current plugin google() is included.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
    // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
    // Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
    google()
    ...
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
}
}
```

**Second** - Update values in distributionURL gradle-wrapper.properties and sync

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

distributionUrl path could be found at following path

[image]

Comment: TheAnkush, my settings already match what you suggest, exactly. But I don't know what you mean by "and sync".

Comment: @HerrimanCoder by Sync I mean gradle sync. Just rebuild the project. Ideally it should work. Are you on a company network that is restricted? Also, Invalidate cache and restart after making changes.

Comment: My settings already matched yours, but after I cleaned and rebuilt, it worked.